# Regex: matching domain.com and any subdomains to domain.com?

Tags: regex

Hi folks I've been at this for 2 hours and figured there has to be someone out there with a better solution?

In [this regex case](https://regex101.com/r/2KmYjZ/2/), I need to match all domains and subdomains from bbc. Eg:

```
bbc.com
subdomain.bbc.co.uk
```

But not sites such as

```
another-bbc.com
anotherbbc.com
bbcmore.com
```

I need to keep the "bbc" part flexible so I can use other domains in future such as facebook.

The closest Ive got to is `(.*\.)?bbc\..*` but it's matching anotherbbc.

Please can you help me? Would appreciate this.

Comment: You may try `(.*\.)?(?<=\.|^)bbc\..*` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/bbosyW/1)) or (with separate strings, not at the online tester) `(.*\.)?(?<![^.])bbc\..*`

Comment: Which flavour? `PCRE` (e.g. `PHP`) ?

Comment: I think that adding `^` should work: `^(.*\.)?bbc\..*`.

Comment: Thanks all, its likely PHP. I am using Pi-Hole DNS. Thanks again

Comment: @Wiktor, that works an absolute charm my friend

Comment: Doesn't need to be as complex as the first comment makes it; if you change the `.*` into `.+` it will match one or more characters rather than zero or more, which should solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, but my pattern is equal to `^(.*\.)?bbc\..*`, @Maroun's comment is an improvement. They are equal in the terms of result.

Comment: @Maroun, this solution also works a charm. Thank you so much everyone. While you're here, check out Pi-Hole its a great tool to help cut down tracking and analytics. I know as devs we have to work with them but for home use, theyre worth every bit.

Answer (score 0):

The following one should suit your needs:

```
^([^.\r\n]+\.)*(bbc\.com|bbc\.co\.uk)$
```

Allows any amount of subdomains for the hardcoded domains.

For this specific case, you could replace `(bbc\.com|bbc\.co\.uk)` with `bbc\.(com|co\.uk)`, but if you need other domains as well (e.g. like you said, `facebook.com`), I believe it will be more maintainable to hardcode them entirely.

See https://regex101.com/r/PnMYpY/1.